# DAO Design Pattern vs DBUnit Code

Tags: java, design-patterns, junit, dao, dbunit

I am not sure if my DAO or DBUnit Test needs some refactoring. Can somebody please guide on the situation that I am facing?

I have a DAO that gets some data from the DB by getting a `Connection` object and then it closes all the resources(`ResultSet`, `Statement` and `Connection`).

I am testing this DAO using DBUnit framework where I am doing two DB operations in this DBUnit Test here:
1) Creating a table and then loading data from XML dataset file
2) Testing the actual `getDataById(int id)` method present in the DAO

The problem is that my second `getDataById(id)` method is not able to get a DB connnection object because my DAO already closed it while performing step 1 above.

The code snippet that actually releases all the resources is shown below.

**DAO.java (Code snippet)**

```
public void releaseResources(ResultSet rs, Statement stmt, Connection cn) {
        System.out.println("rs = " + rs);
        System.out.println("stmt = " + stmt);
        System.out.println("cn = " + cn);
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (cn != null) {
                cn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception while closing DB resources rs, stmt or cn......." + ex);
        }
    }
```

Hence in order to get my DBUnit tests to work I had to overload the above releaseResources() method so that it does not close the connection object which  could be used in my `getDataById(int id)` unit test. Shown below.

**DAO.java (Code snippet with overloaded method) **

```
//OVERLOADED JUST TO GET DBUNIT TESTS WORKING !!! :(
public void releaseResources(Statement stmt) {
    System.out.println("\nReleasing db resources now.... 1111");
    System.out.println("stmt = " + stmt);
    try {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception while closing DB resources stmt......." + ex);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is right design. Can somebody please guide on as how can I improve this?

Complete code is shown below for further reference.

**StateDaoTest.java**

```
public class StateDaoTest {

    protected static Connection connection;
    protected static HsqldbConnection dbunitConnection;
    protected static StateDao dao = new StateDao();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupDatabase() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:my-project-test;shutdown=true");
        dbunitConnection = new HsqldbConnection(connection, null);
    }

    @Before
    public void createTable() throws SQLException {
        dao.setConnection(connection);
        dao.createTables();
    }

    protected IDataSet getDataSet(String name) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(name);
        assertNotNull("file" + name + " not found in classpath", inputStream);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        FlatXmlDataSet dataset = new FlatXmlDataSet(reader);
        return dataset;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void closeDatabase() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("\ninto the closeDatabase() method...");
        System.out.println("connection = " + connection);
        System.out.println("dbunitConnection = " + dbunitConnection);
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
        }
        if (dbunitConnection != null) {
            dbunitConnection.close();
            dbunitConnection = null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStateById() throws Exception {
        IDataSet setupDataSet = getDataSet("/states.xml");
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbunitConnection, setupDataSet);
        State state = dao.getStateById(1);
        assertNotNull(state);
        assertEquals("Pennsylvania", state.getName());
        assertEquals("PA", state.getStateCode());
        assertNotNull(state.getTaxPct());
        assertEquals("Y", state.getActive());
    }

}
```

**StateDao.java**

```
public class StateDao {

    private Connection connection;

    public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    //added for dbunit tests
    public void createTables() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE states (stateId INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1), "
                + "stateCd VARCHAR(10), name VARCHAR(20), taxPct NUMERIC, active CHAR(1))";
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(sql);
        } finally {
            releaseResources(stmt);
        }
    }

    public State getStateById(long id) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE stateId = " + id;

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        State state = null;

        System.out.println(sql);

        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs != null && rs.next()) {
                String stateId = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("stateId"));
                String stateCd = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("stateCd"));
                String name = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("name"));
                String taxPct = StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(rs.getString("taxPct"), "0");
                String active = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("active"));
                state = new State(new Integer(stateId), stateCd, name, new BigDecimal(taxPct), active);
                System.out.println("state = " + state);
            }
            System.out.println("state = " + state);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception whiile fetching data for a state......." + ex);
        } finally {
            releaseResources(rs, stmt, connection);
        }
        return state;
    }

    public void releaseResources(ResultSet rs, Statement stmt, Connection cn) {
        System.out.println("\nReleasing db resources now....2222");
        System.out.println("rs = " + rs);
        System.out.println("stmt = " + stmt);
        System.out.println("cn = " + cn);
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (cn != null) {
                cn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception while closing DB resources rs, stmt or cn......." + ex);
        }
    }

    //added for dbunit tests
    public void releaseResources(Statement stmt) {
        System.out.println("\nReleasing db resources now.... 1111");
        System.out.println("stmt = " + stmt);
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception while closing DB resources stmt......." + ex);
        }
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep using the overloaded `releaseResources` method. If the connection is being passed in from outside, then the dao doesn't own it and shouldn't be closing it. Instead, the connection should be closed separately by the same class that creates it. So `getStateById` should be changed to close only the resultSet and statement, and the connection should be closed elsewhere.

You can add extra overloads of `releaseResources` to take resultSet and statement, or if you're using Java 7 - you can create a single method: `releaseResouces(Closeable... closeables)`. I would make this method a public static method of a separate class so that any class can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use two connections - one for the production code, one for dbUnit.

This is irrelevant of how the DAO obtains the connection - method parameter, DI, lookup (e.g. JNDI).  I've often had a config of a datasource for production code and simple JDBC connection for dbUnit.

It's also safer to use two connections as it forces the production code to complete/commit before the dbUnit connection can see it.  This truly proves the production code works.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying here but what if I want to test multiple  DAO methods such as `getProductById(int id)` and `getAllProducts() in the same dbunit test`. Won't the connection be closed after the first method call? Won't I have to reopen the connection by defining `getConnection()` somewhere in dbunit test case and then calling it. Can you provide an example of how this can be achieved? I am just hesitant to open a new DB connection everytime a test method gets executed.

Comment: Your production connection has the problem.  That's the design of your DAO: it receives an open connection in the constructor and then closes it after first use.  The test isn't the problem; the test shows the production code problem.

Having a second connection for dbUnit means that connection doesn't close until the test shutdown.

Comment: Yes I agree that it's the actual DAO design which is the issue here. Can you provide some code example(s) on how to refactor/redesign this DAO  so that it is more unit testable?